# Specified cast is not valid for float

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to show the Gridview Column Total on footer using Linq Query.

```
GridView1.Columns[4].FooterText = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<float>("commission")).Sum().ToString();
```

I'm getting Exception at this line.

Additional Info:

DataType of this Commission Column is Float in my Sql Table.
 How do I Solve this ?

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Please post the exception

Comment: exception Details Added

Comment: may be `commission` contains Blanks spaces...

Comment: I'm 100% sure there is no Spaces sir

Answer (score 0):

**Use Linq [.Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918069.aspx)**

```
string sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<float>("commission")).ToString();
```

OR

```
string sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("commission")).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you,its Throw the same Exception.its working When i Change float as Double.

Comment: @King_Fisher -  try to Change float to Decimal

Comment: Same Exception sir may i know why its doesn't Working while at Float or Decimal .but working in Double

Comment: @King_Fisher - Is there any NULL value in you DataTable for this Colunm ("commission") ??

Comment: i have 9 Rows in my DataTable  each have 1000 .